# OpenFileDialog Filter not working on Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, openfiledialog

I have the following filter set on an OpenFileDialog:

```
MyApp Files (*.ced, *.cdr, *.wrp, *.wrap, *.out) | *.ced; *.cdr; *.wrp; *.wrap; *.out | All Files (*.*) | *.*
```

The problem is that the .out files don't appear. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have , Don't show hidden or System file under my computer. Go to my computer , Tool -> Option and enable show hidden files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to remove the spaces between the semicolons like so:

```
MyApp Files (*.ced, *.cdr, *.wrp, *.wrap, *.out) |*.ced;*.cdr;*.wrp;*.wrap;*.out| All Files (*.*) | *.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your filter expression with the following, should solve the problem

```
OpnefileDlg.Filter = "(*.ced, *.cdr, *.wrp, *.wrap) | *.ced, *.cdr, *.wrp, *.wrap | All Files (*.*) | *.*";
```

Comment: excludes the .out files all together. I want .out files to be displayed and they aren't with my filter for some reason.

Comment: I had removed it while testing, having it there doesn't incur any problem.